# Combine list of json data based on ID

Tags: c#, .net

I have List of JArray like below trying to combine/concatenate the data based on  ID

```
    [{"ID":"A1","color1":"silver"}, {"ID": "A3", "color1": "Yellow"}]
    [{"ID":"A1","color2":"blue","color3":"pink"}]
    [{"ID":"A2","color4":"green"}]
    [{"ID":"A1","color5":"red","color6":"aqua"}]
    [{"ID":"A1","description":"looking for more colors"}]
```

Trying for an output like this

```
[{"ID":"A1",
    "color1":"silver",
    "color2":"blue",
    "color3":"pink", 
    "color4": "",
    "color5":"red",
    "color6":"aqua", 
    "description":"looking for more colors"
      
    },
    
    {"ID":"A2",
    "color1":"",
    "color2":"",
    "color3":"",
    "color4": "green",
    "color5":"",
    "color6":"",
    "description":""
   },
   {
    "ID": "A3",
    "color1": "yellow",
    "color2":"",
    "color3":"", 
    "color4": "",
    "color5":"",
    "color6":"", 
    "description":""
   }
 ]
```

Any suggestion or help into the right direction please.

```
            List<JArray> data = new List<JArray>();
            JArray array = JArray.Parse(s); // s is [{"ID":"A1","color1":"silver"}]
            data.Add(array);

           for (int x = 0; x < data.Count() - 1; x++)
            {
                data[x].Merge(data[x + 1], new JsonMergeSettings
                {
                    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
                });

                var groupedByUserID = data[x].GroupBy(x => x["ID"]).ToList();
                foreach (var item in groupedByUserID)
                {
                    var firstToken = item.First();
                    var remainingToken = item.Values().Except(firstToken);
                    foreach (var i in remainingToken)
                    {
                        if (i.Type == JTokenType.Property)
                            firstToken[((JProperty)i).Name] = ((JProperty)i).Value;
                    }
                    jArray.Add(firstToken);
                }
            }
            var result = jArray.ToString(Formatting.Indented);

            Console.Write(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<JArray> data = new List<JArray> {
    JArray.Parse("[{ 'ID':'A1', 'color1':'silver' }, { 'ID':'A3', 'color1':'Yellow' }]"),
    JArray.Parse("[{ 'ID':'A1', 'color2':'blue', 'color3':'pink' }]"),
    JArray.Parse("[{ 'ID':'A2', 'color4':'green' }]"),
    JArray.Parse("[{ 'ID':'A1', 'color5':'red', 'color6':'aqua' }]"),
    JArray.Parse("[{ 'ID':'A1', 'description':'looking for more colors' }]")
};

var names = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (JObject x in data.SelectMany(arr => arr))
{
    foreach (var kvp in x)
    {
        names.Add(kvp.Key);
    }
}

var result = data
    .SelectMany(arr => arr)
    .GroupBy(token => token.Value<string>("ID"))
    .Select(group =>
    {
        var obj = new JObject();
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            obj[name] = "";
        }
        foreach (JObject x in group)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in x)
            {
                obj[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    });

var jArray = new JArray(result);
Console.WriteLine(jArray);
```

Comment: please check the updated question i have an issue its not picking up if JArray is like [{ 'ID':'A1', 'color1':'silver' }, {'ID': 'A3', 'color1': 'yellow'}] any suggestions please.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was about to post the answer.  exactly  almost the same changes i have made and about to update your answer. You have won :)